# Add a character after a specific character and before a character

Tags: bash, sed

I have a bash script that I need to insert a ' into it after a ( and before a )

```
MYSTRING(FOO_1234_BAR)
```

needs to be

```
MYSTRING('FOO_1234_BAR')
```

From what I've been reading, I should be using sed, but I'm having trouble with the syntax.

Thank you.

Comment: `sed` would be an easy tool to use for this. Have you read up on the regex syntax for `sed`? What specific trouble are you having with the syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***EDIT:*** Adding one more solution simple one of `sed` if Input_file is same as sample shown.

```
sed "s/(/&'/;s/)/'&/"  Input_file
```

Following `sed` may help you on same.

```
sed "s/\([^(]\)(\([^)]*\))/\1('\2')/"    Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
MYSTRING('FOO_1234_BAR')
```

In case you want to save output into Input_file itself then use `sed -i` or in case you need to take backup of Input_file and save the output into Input_file itself then use `sed -i.bak` in above command.

Comment: That's close, but the single quote is on the wrong side.  That results in MYSTRING'(FOO_1234_BAR)'  the quotes need to be inside the parenthesis not out.

Comment: @user1864311, check now and let me know?

Answer (score 0):

another `sed`

```
sed "s/(\(.*\))/('\1')/" file
```